# Lightbox input dialogues

Tags: php, jquery, dialog, lightbox

I'd like to code a lightbox input dialogue in my application (like the one you see when you want to send a facebook message, except with a dark background), and I'm having a hardtime finding a jQuery plugin that does the job.

I've found [Boxy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/boxy/), but it doesn't seem to have options for having a text field in the lightbox dialogue (even though there's a pic for it!), so that's unfortunate.

Which plugin do you suggest that I use to accomplish this? I would love if it works fine with mobile browsers by the way.

Your help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this is what you're looking for : http://chriswanstrath.com/facebox/

**edit:** now that I've checked the link, the plugin has changed since the last time I've used it. I have a prior version of the plugin, wich works fine and is pratically identical to what you see on facebook, so if you're looking for that, just reply and I'll share it.

Comment: Thanks, this looks EXACTLY like what I want. However, I'm not sure how you can close the facebox through javascript (so I can close it after the user submits something for example). Also, are you implying that the plugin isn't working properly anymore?

Comment: About the documentation, check the source code at the beggining, there's some commented instructions on how to close the box with a line of code as long as the other features. I only wanted to say that the plugin was visually similar to facebox, but now the layout is slighty changed, as you can see from facebox.

Comment: something like jQuery(document).trigger('close.facebox');

Answer (score 0):

take a look at http://www.gettopup.com/
You can put anything in (Take a closer look at the 'open google' example.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks alot. Same question though: how do I make it close (through code) after the user does an action in the loaded HTML?